# Converting a list into TreeViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, list, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a list of `TransactionTypes` and I want each of these to be added as `Nodes` / `TreeViewItems` on a TreeView, under another `TreeViewItem` called `'Audit'`.

Is there a way to convert each individual item in the list into a new `TreeViewItem` in a TreeView? And if so, how can it be done most efficiently?

Thanks.

EDIT:

We are using a WPF application and therefore can't use .Nodes / TreeNodes.

Comment: what framework version of .NET are you using ?

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
List<TransactionTypes> lstTrans ;
TreeViewItem auditNode ;

//code that initializes lsTrans
//code that initializes auditNode 

foreach(TransactionTypes tt in lstTrans)
{
    auditNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = tt.someStringProperty });
}
```

This is asumming that your `TreeViewItem` has a `header` property and is declared similar to this

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="initialValue"></TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

There is probably a more compact way using LINQ but internally is still a loop

Here is a great example of **[using TreeView in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF)**

Comment: Misunderstood your answer, sorry. Thank you once again!